# zend framework 1 cdata wsdl

Tags: web-services, zend-framework, wsdl, cdata

I have an existing soap webservice that is working but need one element to output data enclosed in the form of `<data><![CDATA[some text]]></data>`.

I tried it but on the xml response the data is outputting as `<data>&lt;[CDATA[some text]]&gt;</data>` instead of `<data><![CDATA[some text]]></data>`.

I read somewhere after googling that zend framework does the encoding of the `<` to `&lt;` and `>` to `&gt;` on cdata automatically before passing it to the xml.

How can I get only `<data><![CDATA[some text]]></data>` instead of `<data>&lt;[CDATA[some text]]&gt;</data>`?